# unit testing and logback

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, logback

while testing a piece of code we normally have assertions to check if a variable was set, if a code of block was executed, etc., but we don't normally test if the right log messages are being saved to the log files.

My environment is Java, Spring, Mockito, and Logback. I am thinking of using Mockito and inject the log as a datasource. I looked around and could not find a better idea.

Are you aware of an existing system for testing Logback using the existing logback.xml file and that would also support MDC?

On this specific system, we have two loggers. One of the loggers logs normal events, such as "Entered method A", "did something", "exited method A".

Another log is used for auditing. For example, it stores the parameters that were passed in and out of a specific module. There are reports that run off of this log (using MDC) so the tags used and the values for the tags are important and we would like to verify if the MDC tags contain the values of the parameters. But, as I said, these values should go only to the audit log, and not to the "normal" log, so, beyond testing that the values go to the audit log, we want to test that they DID NOT go to the other log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your not doing diagnostic logging but application event logging.

If its diagnostic logging .. stop you don't need to test it. Its like unit testing for assertions or unit testing for your unit testing.

If its application event logging and you are just really **unit** testing then you should just make a `protected` helper method that actually calls the logger. Then in your unit test you just extend the class under test and subclass the helper method to set a variable that your test reads after being called (no special mocking library or scary reflection). Or if you want to create more work you can just make a helper component with that an interface that does the event logging for you and mockito that.

If you really want to check the output of the logging then I think you should go full on **integration** testing and maybe even create a separate project with a custom logback.xml.
Also integration testing will be the only way to fully test the **MDC** since its threadlocal based and god knows what other components will bind to it.

What I mean by integration testing in terms of Spring is to load up most of your application (ie the ApplicationContext XML or Java Configuration you are going to use for real) and not using any mocks. Spring luckily helps quite a bit on this.

Comment: This is actually one of the ways I was going about it. Instead of using a logger, inject another class that would behave just like the logger but would check if the values are present. The problems, I won't list here because you already mentioned them.